# A module that allows user to create content anonymously, then if they register, assigns the content to them

Tags: 7

I recall a module I came across that was in dev a while back that basically allowed users to create nodes as an anonymous user. Then if they registered on the site, it assigned authorship of these nodes to that user account. Similar to how Drupal Answers works. It helps to lower the threshold for someone to get involved in a site. I just cannot recall the name.

Does anyone know?

Comment: a google search led me to [this](http://drupal.org/project/sup) module for D6, maybe you could browse the related modules and get lucky

Answer (score 4):

You should use [Create and Register](http://drupal.org/project/create_and_reg) module.

> This module creates a "lazy registration" which means that the user creates the content first and after this logs in or registers to the site.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Create and Register](https://drupal.org/project/create_and_reg) (already mentioned by hosszu.kalman), Lazy registration is also possible with [Anonymous Publishing](https://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing).

Disclosure: I am one of the maintainers of Anonymous Publishing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some module custom programing or using Rules module.

1. Create a custom field on the content type and use [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions).
2. After each content it is created by anonymous user, add to this field special session value.
3. After the user registers assign the content identified with the session value to the user.