# Allow anonymous users to post content but require login/register before it is saved

Tags: users

I have a website with a node form displayed as a block on the frontpage. This is done to make sure users get down to posting content easily and quickly.

However I'm interested in saving details of the poster so they can later be notified of comments, etc to their node. I would like for the user to then be required to login or register before their content is posted.

So from nodeform block, they click Save and then they are asked to login or register..After that content is saved.

Is there any module that does this, or what approach can I take to code my own?

Thanks

Comment: Nearly positive this was asked and answered a few days ago.

Comment: Mind directing to where it was discussed? Thanks

Comment: MPD may refer to this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53470/how-can-anonymous-users-be-allowed-to-post-while-still-maintaining-content-integ/54025 or this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/use-email-to-validate-post-not-unlike-craigslist It is not the same question, but it they cover similar ground.

Comment: Sorry, was on tablet.  It was http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/31851/835  The use cases is slightly different b/c anonymous notifications, so I am not considering this a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module that does something similar (**Anonymous Publishing**) http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing - I.e. it rolls posting and registering into one process, but delays publication of content until the user confirms his identity by means of an verification email.

The anonymous user is not formally registered as a *user*, but his email is kept on file in a visitors table, so the effect is very similar.

There is also a submodule named **Anonymous Publishing Claim** that allows the anonymous user to "claim" any content posted before he/she registered if he/she later decides to register as a regular user.

I want this functionality for myself for Drupal 7, so I've ported it to Drupal 7. I'll appreciate help with this, both for testing and for writing code.  Please use the project page on Drupal.org for such interventions (not DrupalAnswers.SE).

Answer (score 7):

This module might be worth looking at as well: [Create and Register](https://www.drupal.org/project/create_and_reg). Below are some more details about this module, and how it works (summary from the module's project page).

> This module allows an anonymous user to create the content. After
>   doing so the user must login (or registers to the site). Here are some
>   more details about the process to do so:
>
> - anonymous user creates a content.
> - the user will be redirected to the login page (if you set it on the settings form) after the user finished the node creation.
> - the user registers or logs in.
> - the created node(s) will be assigned to the user after logging in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [inline_registration](https://drupal.org/project/inline_registration) project and combine it with both [email_registration](https://drupal.org/project/email_registration) and either [genpass](https://drupal.org/project/genpass) or [registration_toboggan](https://drupal.org/project/registration_toboggan).

In effect, this adds an e-mail field to the form for anonymous node posting. An account will be created at the same time as posting a node, and the password and activation link sent to the new user.

You can have the same functionality for comment posting as well by adding  [comment_registration](https://drupal.org/project/comment_registration).

Answer (score -1):

anonymous users can post their answers without logging in/registering and if they want to receive notification when have new comment you can give an option to check/uncheck. Very easy.

Comment: Sorry, but how does it answer OP's question?